# ggplot() geom_boxplot() how to change point styles for different treatments

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am looping to make boxplots with ggplot. I want to customize the look of the box plots with color and using different point styles. I have color formatting working but I cannot get the point style to change. I am using the following to make the graphs:

```
variables <- met_df %>%
  select(28, 30:34, 38:62, 93:101, 103:106, 112:114, 140:168, 172:184, 190:202, 208:216, 219:224, 226:236, 238:245, 267:275,278 ,334 , 341, 344:347, 358:365, 474:516) %>%
  names()
 
for(i in variables) {
  g <- ggplot(met_df, aes(x = Rx, y = get(i), color= Rx)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA)+
    ylab(i)
  print(g + theme_classic()+ geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2))+ color_4)
}
```

For the color I used:

```
color_4 <- list(scale_color_manual(
  values = c("gray60", "midnightblue", "steelblue2", "dodgerblue3"),
  name = "Treatment",
  labels = c("Control", "Metformin", "Met Early", "Met Late")
))
```

I have tried the following for the points:

```
point_4_v2 <- list(scale_shape_manual(
  values = c(23, 22, 21, 24),
  name = "Treatment",
  labels = c("Control", "Metformin", "Met Early", "Met Late")
))
```

However, that did not work.

Comment: To get different shapes you have to map on the `shape` aes.

Comment: Do you really need all of those separate plots? Perhaps `met_df %>% select(...) %>% pivot_longer(-Rx) %>% ggplot(aes(Rx, value, color=Rx)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~name)`? It'd be a bit easier if working with sample data, either yours or public data that you can adapt to your code.